# 'Novelty only' prior art

Tags: patentability, novelty

Can someone explain to me the meaning of novelty only prior art, and the difference between this and regular prior art? Thanks.

Comment: Is this in the context of a non-US prosecution?

Comment: You have a relevant discussion about this topic [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/24525/why-is-art-543-epc-limited-to-only-european-patent-applications). It refers to the European patent practice but could be valid for many other jurisdictions.

Comment: @theEuropeist you might post that as an answer

Comment: Can you link to where you've seen that phrase? Could it have been "novelty over prior art"?

Answer (score 0):

You have a relevant discussion about this topic [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/24525/why-is-art-543-epc-limited-to-only-european-patent-applications). It refers to the European patent practice but could be valid for many other jurisdictions.

Pretty much, the novelty requirement is meant to avoid 2+ patents on the same subject-matter in a same jurisdiction, otherwise a third party will have to get 2+ licenses for the very same subject-matter, which is unfair given that they are for the same invention. By limiting the novelty requirement to patents and patent applications of a same jurisdiction you could have the same monopoly in the respective jurisdiction and somewhere else, and that somewhere else is not a problem because the third party needs the license per jurisdiction.

Comment: Link only answers are less that ideal. Perhaps you could summarize the relevant information here.